# Was God's motive for barring man from eating of the "tree of knowledge" as given by the serpent true?

Tags: genesis, historical-interpretation, context

According to the serpent in Genesis 3:5, God's motive for prohibiting man from eating from the "tree of knowledge" was that man shall not become godly like him,

> For God knows that when you eat from it your eyes will be opened, and
>   you will be like God, knowing good and evil. (NIV)

This daring statement of the serpent I interpret as: God is jealous of man, and afraid that he may one day rival him, so he bars him from eating the fruit that can make him godlike.

My question is, was this God's true motive according to the biblical author, or was this a lie just like the first part of the serpent's statement (that Adam and Eve would not certainly die). What else could have been the reason for God prohibiting man from eating from "the tree of knowledge"?

What evidence do you have to support either way?

**Clarification**: From the answers and comments that were posted it seems like my question was misunderstood, so let me rephrase it: my question was not *whether the declaration that man would die if they eat from it, is true*, in fact I think this declaration was true and even fulfilled. My question is whether *the motive given in the serpent's dialogue, for God's prohibition, is true or false*, that is the crux of my question and if answers could focus on that, it would be appreciated.

Comment: God warned that eating would result in death. And now, we all die. God's warning was real and true. And it has come to pass.

Comment: Another possibility virtually ignored in western Christianity is that Adam and Eve would one day be permitted to eat of the tree of knowledge of good and evil, but they were not yet ready to do so at that point in the creation narrative.

Comment: I was stating the historical facts, from which the 'motive' may be clearly seen.

Comment: I suppose Adam and Eve got to know the distinction between good and evil when Cain murdered Able.

Comment: @Constantthin They learned to distinguish good and evil when they ate the fruit of the Tree of Knowledge of Good *and* Evil... and their "eyes were opened" (Gen 3:7).

Comment: `Didn't we learn, negative plus negative equals positive` - yes.  But our English professors also taught us that double-negatives are not recommended because they can lead to this kind of confusion that you are seeing, so I have edited that. Please revert if this edit if you object.

Comment: @Xiota. Well, I don't know if walking around naked, and eating poisoned fruit, is evil. It is certainly bad, but if it was evil it would have been included in the Ten Commandments.

Comment: @Constantthin 1. Though knowing they are naked is a consequence of their eyes being "opened", it is not necessarily "good" or "evil". 2. That "knowing good and evil" was a consequence of eating the fruit is stated directly by Yahweh in Gen 3:22. 3. It's also in the name of the tree. 4. The text indicates, multiple times, that the fruit was *not* poisonous. 5. "The" Ten Commandments are not the end-all, be-all of Yahweh's commands. Jews count over 600 commandments. For instance, everyone who has ever worn a cotton-blend has done "evil". 6. Why is it evil? Only God knows.

Comment: @Xiota. Regarding your point 4; I should have put the word "poisonous" within inverted commas. The other points are matters of semantics.

Comment: @Constantthin Semantics should not be cast aside so carelessly unless your intent *really* is to make an *entirely* symbolic argument.  If that's the case, you can switch all occurrences of "good" with "evil", and vice versa, as well on other opposing concepts.

Comment: @Xiota. I think you hit the nail on the head there. The difficulty is of course to find the right method in interpreting bible passages. It is a huge challenge. Most, if not all, of us can probably often admit lack of wisdom. Not forgetting that "the word is a two edged sword" (Heb 4:12), cutting more than one way. Thus, more than one interpretation is often possible.

Comment: *You will be like God, knowing good and evil* is not quite the same as *you will be like God in all things*. God, apart from knowing evil, also has the power to resist its temptation, something man usually does not.

Comment: @JamesShewey I do not appreciate such extensive editing to my posts. Next time please consult me before you attempt such extensive editing. Thank you.

Comment: Must it be that YHVH Elohim was jealous? Perhaps the point of the scenario was to help man become like Him. Assuming omnipotence, God would have known the serpent's (traditionally the serpent is to femininity & fertility what is the bull is to masculinity & virility) actions beforehand. It then seems that "the Fall" is part of the process of "creating man in His image." IOW, mankind couldn't be ready to learn from pain until we first learned for ourselves the difference between pleasure and pain. See also: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/43738/was-the-fall-of-man-really-a-fall

Comment: Much of this comment thread is focused on "good" and "evil." Please note that the Hebrew words are more closely related to "pleasure" and "pain." Before the incident, they only knew pleasure, afterward (it is my understanding that) they saw the pain which already existed, but had not yet previously experienced. This doesn't necessarily mean that "pleasure & pain" was made real—only that they were now able to experience it, like YHVH Elohim.

Answer (score 3):

> The serpent makes four claims in Gen 3:5, (1) **"For Elohim knows** that (2) **when *(on the day)* you eat from it your eyes will be opened**, and (3) **you will be like Elohim**, (4) **knowing good and evil**."
>
> 1. "For Elohim knows" – What God does or does not know is theological opinion. Most people would agree that it would be reasonable for God to know the consequence of eating the fruit given that it is stated in the name of the tree.
> 2. Gen 3:7, "Then the eyes of both of them were opened..." – The man and woman likely recognized the experience themselves as it occurred.
> 3. Gen 3:22, Yahweh-Elohim says, "The man has now *become like one of us*..."
> 4. "...knowing good and evil..."
>
> So of these four claims by the serpent, one is directly verified by the man and woman, two are verified by Yahweh himself, and the remaining, only God knows. While the *text* does present the serpent more favorably than Yahweh, **Yahweh's "true motivations" are never explicitly stated**, so all anyone can do is *speculate*.
>
> However, the events of this and other stories, as well as Yahweh's own words, are consistent with the portrayal of Yahweh as "jealous" (Exodus 34:14). If you are concerned about the theological implications of contradictory portrayals of God, see the end of the third part of this answer.

---

**God and the serpent make several other claims** in Gen 2-3, which I will address.

In Gen 3:4, the serpent tells the woman, “You will not certainly die”?

- Gen 3:6 implies that Eve's previous understanding was that the fruit was poisonous. (When she saw that it was *good for food*, pleasant to the eyes, and desirable for wisdom...)
- Gen 3:16 – Dying is *not* part of Eve's punishment.
- Gen 3:17-19 – Dying is *not* part of Adam's punishment.
- Gen 3:22 – Dying is *not* a *punishment* or *consequence* of *eating* the fruit. Man is allowed to live, just not *forever* – because of "knowing good and evil", *not* because of *eating* the fruit.
- Gen 5:5 – Adam does die, but was it *really* related to eating the fruit? Why isn't there a flashback to the garden? There are other examples in the Bible where distant events are mentioned as the rationale for a command or action of God when it wouldn't otherwise be clear.
- Eve's death is not mentioned at all. Could she perhaps be still living now? (The Bible is *not* a complete record.)
- We could quibble about the meaning of "certainly die". The Hebrew is a reduplicated verb. It can be thought of similarly to "it will kill you dead". When God uses the phrase (Gen 2:17), it's pretty clear a fairly quick death is meant because he specifies "on the day". The serpent gives the same time frame in Gen 3:5.
- The phrase may also be interpreted as an introductory clause rather than a complete statement in itself. – "Not kill you dead, for Elohim knows..."
- Some interpret "on the day" to mean "when". It's a stretch to think that the time frame should be on the order of hundreds of years rather than seconds, minutes, hours, or days. A thought experiment to illustrate this in a bit.

In Gen 2:17, Yahweh-Elohim states, "on the day *(or when)* you eat this, you will surely die"? The implication is that the fruit is likely poisonous. This is indicated in Gen 3:6 when the woman sees that the fruit was *good for food* – agreeable for eating – not poisonous. Further, consider this thought experiment:

- Suppose I place a slice of durian before you and say, "on the day *(or when)* you eat this, you will surely die". Does it at all sound as if the fruit is likely poisonous? Suppose the fruit is not poisonous. Am I lying about the fruit and death?
- Now suppose you eat the fruit.

  - While you might *feel* like dying (it has an... acquired taste), you won't. Now suppose you do die several hundred years later. Did I lie to you about the fruit and dying? Would it matter if I said "on the day" vs "when"?
  - Suppose you happen to have an occult heart disease (hidden, not supernatural). As the durian passes through your esophagus, you have an arrhythmia and die. Was I telling you the truth about the fruit and dying? What if you survive the immediate arrhythmia, but die of another one several hundred years later?
- The truthfulness of the statement is really an open question. However, far fewer mental gymnastics are required to justify the claim that Yahweh was at least somewhat deceptive. This is not a problem theologically, as I will explain momentarily.

---

**God is portrayed very differently in the Old Testament than he is commonly described in modern times.** The core attribute of God that ancient people were most concerned with is *power*. The attribute modern Christians tend to be concerned with is *love* or *goodness*. This difference explains why:

- Ancients believed God *is* capable of deception. See I Kings 22:23 and II Chronicles 18:22, where Yahweh explicitly sends a "lying spirit" to the prophets.
- Ancients believed God *is* capable of manipulating human actions toward "evil". See multiple verses in Exodus, including 9:12, where every time pharaoh was about to free the Hebrews, Yahweh "hardened pharaoh's heart". See Romans 9:17, where it is explained that God's purpose is to demonstrate his power.
- Ancients believed God *did intend* to subjugate people. See any of numerous verses stating that the relationship between God and humans is equivalent to that between master and slave. See also Genesis 11:6, where Yahweh states, “If as one people speaking the same language they have begun to do this, then nothing they plan to do will be impossible for them."
- God states, in Isaiah 45:7, "I form light and create darkness. I make peace and create evil. I, Yahweh, do all these things."

  Some people claim "evil" should be translated "calamity", "destruction", "chaos", etc. This is pointless hair splitting because – is it really any better for God to rain down destruction and chaos than "evil"? In ancient times, "evil" and "calamity" were synonymous concepts. It is the same word when God sees the "wickedness" of mankind. – The point is that God is *powerful*.

Recall the **parable of the [blind men and the elephant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_men_and_an_elephant)**. People at different times have had different views of God. **None are correct.** Even in aggregate, they are no more correct than it is to claim:

- elephant = wall + tree + rope + fan + spear + snake.

Comment: The blind man and the elephant assumes The Elephant doesn’t reveal himself by divine inspiration in a Bible! There’s no need to guess, if God tells you, especially when you can still ask the author today what He meant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96058/discussion-between-bach-and-god).

Comment: This is a very good answer. I would, however, add the word "being" to the sentence "The core attribute of God that ancient people were most concerned with is power." The name Elohim references his power while the name YHVH references his being. That is, anything with power (or "transfer of energy") has power because of the first power—without the first power, there are no other powers. Similarly, anything which exists does so because something else first existed. There is no being from non-being, thus all that is owes its existence to the first thing which existed. YHVH Elohim is first of both

Comment: @RubelliteFae I don't understand your comment or why you think the word "being" needs to be inserted. Electricity is power, but few would claim that it is God or that God is electricity. But there have been gods whose strength came from wielding (what we now know to be) electrical power.

Comment: Not sure how to at you on the app (can't copy-paste your name). The etymology of Elohim is rooted in might/power. I'll have to look up the passage,  but I recall reading that His power is that which enables anything to have power.  This could imply either "first cause / prime mover" or a pervasive nature (imminence). Wrt "being," this is found in yhe etymology of YHVH and is backed up by (what is commonly translated to) "I am that I am." Regardless of how many people would make the claim (appeal to popularity), this is what the Hebrew shows.

Comment: It doesn't mean that electricity is God,  but that there could be no electricity without Elohim

Answer (score 2):

The question, as clarified, is whether the motive given by the serpent for God’s prohibition is true or false.

---

First there is the matter of what the Biblical text actually says.  The King James translation of the Masoretic Text reads *ye shall be as gods* (plural, miniscule).  Two Jewish translations are similar:

> *But God knows that as soon as you eat of it your eyes will be opened and you will be like divine beings who know good and bad* (JPS Tanakh)
>
> *For God knows that on the day that you eat thereof, your eyes will be opened, and you will be like angels, knowing good and evil* ([Rosenberg translation](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/63255/jewish/The-Bible-with-Rashi.htm))

A midrash from the Talmud ([Pirkei DeRabbi Eliezer 13](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_DeRabbi_Eliezer.13?lang=bi)) explains:

> Just as He creates worlds and destroys worlds, so will ye be able to create worlds and to destroy worlds. Just as He slays and brings to life, so also will ye be able to kill and to bring to life

The Septuagint reading is similar:

> ᾔδει γὰρ ὁ θεὸς ὅτι ἐν ἧ ἂν ἡμέρᾳ φάγητε ἀπʼ αὐτοῦ, διανοιχθήσονται ὑμῶν οἱ ὀφθαλμοί, καὶ ἔσεσθε ὡς θεοὶ γινώσκοντες καλὸν καὶ πονηρόν.
>
> For God knew that in whatever day ye should eat of it your eyes would be opened, and ye would be as gods (θεοὶ), knowing good and evil (Brenton translation).

So the NIV translation, *... like God ...* (singular, majuscule), might be a little liberal.

---

With the above in mind, the question becomes whether God forbade Adam (and Eve, to whom Adam presumably later explained the prohibition) to partake of the tree of knowledge because (1) their eyes would be opened and (2) they would become like gods, (in the sense of) knowing good and evil.

---

As seems to be the case with what the devil says, there was truth mixed with falsehood or at least irony.  In his extensive commentary on Genesis, the 20th century Eastern Orthodox writer Seraphim Rose states:

> The temptation offered by the devil contains the same elements we fallen men know in our own fight against sin.  He offers, first of all, not an obvious evil but something which seems good and true.  Men were indeed created to be *gods and sons of the most high* (Psalm 82:6) … In causing our first ancestors to look at the good thing of becoming like gods, the devil hoped to cause them to forget the “small” commandment.<sup>1</sup>

---

Their eyes were in fact opened, but they were opened to the fact that they were deprived of grace.  John Chrysostom comments here:

> It was not the eating of the tree that opened their eyes: they had seen even before eating.  But since this eating served as an expression of disobedience and violation of the commandment given by God, and for this reason they were then deprived of the glory that clothed them, having become unworthy of such great honor, the Scripture says:  They ate, and their eyes were opened, and they knew that they were naked.  Being deprived of the grace from on high for the transgression of the commandment, they saw also their physical nakedness, so that from the shame that took hold of them they might understand into what an abyss they had been cast by the transgression of the Master's commandment ... When you hear, "their eyes were opened," understand this to mean that God gave them to feel their nakedness and the loss of glory they had enjoyed prior to eating.<sup>2</sup>

---

Furthermore, they also do come to know good and evil, but through the consequence of their transgression and not through some quasi-magical effect of the fruit itself:

> The tree itself represents the knowledge of evil, since tasting of it meant disobeying the commandment.  Adam learned about evil through his disobedience.   He chose the way of sin and thereby discovered in bitter experience what it meant to be evil, and then to repent of that evil and come back to goodness.<sup>3</sup>

---

I think we must conclude, therefore, that the serpent may have been speaking the literal truth about God's motive, though it was presented and probably understood in a very warped sense.

---

<sup>1.</sup> <sup>*Genesis, Creation and Early Man: The Orthodox Christian Vision* (2d ed.; St. Herman of Alaska Brotherhood, 2011), p.256</sup>
<sup>2.</sup>  <sup>In *Genesis, Creation and Early Man*, p. 259.</sup>
<sup>3.</sup>  <sup>*Ibid.*, p.233</sup>

Comment: If what the serpent said was true then one can only wonder why God would bar man from becoming godlike. Was god being selfish?

Comment: @Bach, the Patristic understanding was not that God was being selfish, but rather that man was not yet prepared for what God ultimately had in store for him.  In this view, the essence of man's transgression was pride - attempting to achieve something on one's own quickly rather than with God's help in the time God had intended.  There is a great deal of discussion of this in the book by Seraphim Rose (an Eastern Orthodox monk) that I reference.  There is another question floating around related to the one you posted here that I was going to try to study and offer an answer on.

Comment: "the essence of man's transgression was pride" How can man have transgressed before having a conception of morality?

Comment: Why do you assume he had no conception of morality?

Answer (score 1):

If we think of God as the as the origin of all knowledge and that man was to learn form him (Eccl 12:13-14) this would make God their ruler as he would have to teach humans right from wrong as Adam was created with a blank sheet for a mind which his creator would help him to fill with all kinds of good information to help them, Adam & Eve, to care for the and to fill the earth with humans:-

> NIV Gen. 1:28 "God blessed them and said to them, “Be fruitful and increase in number; fill the earth and subdue it. Rule over the fish in the sea and the birds in the sky and over every living creature that moves on the ground.”

So God gave them a direct COMMAND they MUST obey (Gen 2:2:17); not to eat from the tree of Knowledge of good and bad, showing that he as their maker was also their ruler having the right to tell them what is Good and Bad, not to decide for themselves; which is what the Tree stood for:-

> NIV Acts 5:29 "“We must obey God as ruler . . ."

So for Eve then Adam to do what God had COMMANDED them (see Gen 2:16) NOT to do was a attack on his rulership over them, thus over all future offspring of theirs; if their children would do as God says or disobey like Adam and Eve did?

The result of eating from the Tree God told them not to eat from and thus rejecting him a their ruler was death:-

> NIV Gen 2:17 "but you must not eat from the tree of the knowledge of good and evil, for when you eat from it ***you will certainly die.”***

You ask if all this is true; well humans die:-

> NIV  1 Cor. 15:22 "For as in Adam all die ..."
>
> NWT Romans 5:12 "That is why, just as through one man sin entered into the world and death through sin, and so death spread to all men because they had all sinned—.2

As to disobey what God has told them as a rejection of his rulership over them; to do as The Devil (Serpent) told them to do was to except them as their NEW ruler:-

[]  Added

> NWT 1 John 3:8  "The one who practices sin [e.g. disobeys God; like Adam & Eve] originates with the Devil [the both did as He said] , because the Devil has been sinning from the beginning [influenced Adam & eve to reject what God said (Gen. 3:3-5)]."

Adam and Eve became their own gods (Gen 3:5b) it that they now decided what was good and bad for themselves instead of The Almighty God who made the point that was his domain as at:-

> NWT  Exodus 19:5 "***Now if you will strictly obey my voice*** and keep my covenant, you will certainly become my special property out of all peoples, for the whole earth belongs to me."

The Big Issue!!

Comment: If you read hermeneutics.stackexchange.com, you will surely die. (O snaps.)

Comment: Qal verbs are to be taken as mitzvot. That is, "it is best for you (not) to _" rather than "I will punish you if you do (not) _."

Answer (score 1):

The tree of the knowledge of good and evil represents the true God's sovereignty, his right to rule over what he had created. In other words, only the true God could rule in such a way for deciding what was in the best interests of what he created (good) and what wasn't in the best interests of what he created (evil).

The True God wanted Adam to have faith or exercise faith when he forbid Adam to not eat of the forbidden tree, God wanted Adam to exercise faith that it was in his best interests for him to obey that command. God wants mankind to understand that having such love for the True God that you will exercise faith that he knows what is in the best interests of what he created and what isn't in the best interests of what he created.

The True Gods motive regarding the tree of the knowledge of good and evil is for man to have faith that what he tells mankind what to do or what not to do it's in mankind best interests to obey God because God is love and all his commands are about the love he has for his creation. It's God's sovereignty that's in the best interests of creation. God's arrangement of ruling over his creation his sovereignty is what we are to exercise faith in.

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).

Comment: @Barney:  an excellent answer but  please include scriptures to make your answer more convincing , like Revelation 4;11 and Psalms 24:1 +1

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's true, as Gen 3:22 "Behold, the man has become like one of us in knowing good and evil", says. However, the reason is not jealousy, but God doesn't want their suffering or death. God is depicted as a parent who does not want his children to grow up but remain innocent. You must keep in mind that the story is a parabolic ancient story explaining man's growth to maturity, & the consequence of sin, the necessity of depending on God, not on Satan. Saint Pelagius wrote in his [letter to Demetrius](http://www.edwinhopper.com/31%20Pelagius%20Letter%20to%20Demetrias.pdf) in 413 AD with an accurate interpretation:

> Before eating
> the fruit they did not know the difference between good and evil; thus they did not
> possess the knowledge which enables human beings to exercise freedom of choice. By
> eating the fruit they acquired this knowledge, and from that moment onwards they were
> free. Thus the story of their banishment from Eden is in truth the story of how the human
> race gained its freedom: by eating fruit from the tree of knowledge, Adam and Eve
> became mature human beings, responsible to God for their actions.
> How is it possible, then, for an act of disobedience to God to bring such a blessing? When
> Adam and Eve lived in the Garden of Eden they were like small children: they simply
> obeyed God’s instructions without considering the moral reasons for those instructions. To
> become mature they needed to learn the distinction for themselves between right and
> wrong, good and evil. And God gave them the opportunity to become mature by putting
> within the garden the tree of knowledge, by which they could learn this distinction. But if
> God had simply instructed Adam and Eve to eat from the tree, and they had obeyed, they
> would have been acting like children. So he forbade them from eating the fruit; this meant that they themselves had to make a decision, whether to eat or not to eat. Just as a young person needs to defy his parents in order to grow to maturity, so Adam and Eve needed to defy God in order to share his knowledge of good and evil. By defying God, Adam and Eve grew to maturity in his image.

God is hurt by the suffering and death caused by sin, but he also rejoices when man freely comes to him and earns the tree of life, the right way.

Comment: This is a very novel approach. You are saying that God didn't prohibit them because he didn't want them to eat, on the contrary, God wanted them to eat and defy him! Then why are they punished for eating from it? He should have been proud of them. And why is satan involved? I like this approach, but I have to say that it doesn't exactly square up with the way it is portrayed in the bible. It feels more like a modern 2020 interpretation of a biblical story aimed to make it look more relatable and humane.

Comment: I didn't imply that God wanted them to defy but God didn't want them to eat the fruit. God knew they will defy and grow up. The explanation is 5th century. They were punished for defying him. Satan plays the role of deception misleader. It makes perfect sense. It's not a mythology but mytho parable.

Comment: But why are they punished when they defy him if the whole point is that they "should" defy him and grow up. In other words, if they wouldn't have defied him then would have been like kids forever, which we all agree is not a good thing. So you're saying that God was not having their best interest in mind, and that they were punished for choosing the more logical path, and in some way were doing the "right" thing. I'm having a hard time with this, although I Iike the overall approach.

Comment: Why does God not want them to grow up? I would say God does want them to grow up. God is testing them and giving them the opportunity to grow up. There are consequences for everything, and God had to follow through with his promise that they would become mortal after eating from it, so Adam essentially chose maturity and freedom of choice over immortality. This is the way I prefer to explain it. Thanks for sharing this.

Comment: Nowhere does it mean they should defy him; but only they would defy him to growup. He knew they would, nothing go against his will(grow up); thus God wasn't defeated in the defiance but only hurt by their death. His will they remain innocent is similar to any parent who wants the same protective care for the children. Their punishment symbolizes the consequence of defying his will. Their decision wasn't logical path but natural outcome of growth of man from childhood. God acts as the protective parent, whereas Satan as the adversary who misleads from God's path.

Comment: @Bach read Rambam commentary, and related Ques. Pelagius explanation is more traditional Jewish; whereas the Roman pagan interpretation is the novel one, which mainstream christians follow today. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/118265/13378 related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/105872/who-is-more-truthful-in-the-garden-of-eden-story-god-or-the-serpent The tree represent maturity, ability to do sin and die.

Comment: Yes but Pelagius starts with an important question: "How can defying God bring such a blessing?" Maimonides himself grapples with this question, and so does Ramban. I find Pelagius' answer wanting. He says they needed to defy him in order to grow up. I agree, but that by definition means that their transgression of God's will was a blessing in disguise. But then how can sin bring such a positive outcome? That's what I was asking you all along, and for that reason I'm having a hard time with it.

Comment: The positive outcome is maturity with freedom itself even though it may bring death through sin. Man can freely choose & love God, thus earn the tree of life (obedience) the right way, instead of stealing it. God as a father wants man to remain a child, but he rejoices when man freely loves & unites with him in obedience.

Answer (score 0):

The tree of the knowledge of good and evil represents that God alone has the right to decide what is good for what he created or what is evil for what he created. To put it another way God alone knows what is in the best interests of what he created (good) or what's not in the best interests of what he created. (evil) The serpent saying, "For God knows that in the very day you eat from it, your eyes will be opened and you will be like God, knowing good and bad," was making them (Adam and Eve) wrongly believe that God was withholding something good from them. The serpent implied that humans would be happier if they didn't obey God.

In Genesis 3:22 God says, "the man has become like one of us in knowing good and bad.” This apparently did not mean merely having knowledge of what was good and what was bad for them, for the first man and woman had such knowledge by reason of God’s commands to them. Furthermore, God’s words in Genesis 3:22 could not pertain to their now knowing what was bad by experience, for Jehovah said that they had become like him and God has not learned what is bad by doing bad. (Ps 92:14, 15) Evidently, Adam and Eve got to know what was good and what was bad in the special sense of now judging for themselves what was good and what was bad. They were idolatrously placing their judgment above God’s judgment of what was good or bad for mankind, disobediently becoming a law to themselves, as it were, instead of obeying God, who has both the right and the wisdom necessary to determine good and bad for mankind. So their independent knowledge, or standard, of good and bad was not like that of Jehovah. Rather, it was one that led mankind to misery.​—Jer 10:23.

So the serpent lied to Eve when it said they, meaning she and Adam would be godly like the true God, meaning that was the reason the serpent said God prohibited them from eating from the forbidden tree.

Answer (score -2):

There are several things that are happening here and creating the context might shed some light. However for time sake I will have to plug in verses at a later date

The serpent of old (satan) was a cherub/seraph or a serpentine creature.

He was also a son of God or an elohim.

Jesus says in John 17 that prior to Creation He had a glory. Jesus was also the angel of the Lord or if you like a cherub/seraph as far as all the other “angels” heavenly hosts were concerned.

Jesus was a member of the Godhead that represented the invisible God or we know Him as the Father.

From satan’s vantage point Jesus was the same as himself. Mostly because Jesus had taken off His divine glory prior to Creation. Jesus has at least four different states of being.

- Prior to Creation, glorified God
- After Creation, God but without His glory in appearance a cherub
- Incarnation, God in a non glorified humanlike body
- After resurrection, God in a glorified body.

In satan’s eyes satan wanted to be like the most high and says as much in Isaiah. If the ‘angel of the Lord’ (Jesus), whom the demons knew to be the son of God, if He could be God, why couldn’t satan himself also be God? Consider the train of thought satan might have had.

This was bugging him, that the invisible God was withholding from him the ability to be God too just like this other cherub (Jesus) was God. Lucifer might have even had a higher standing than the angel of the Lord or equal standing other than that title of God.

Further Adam was given dominion over the whole of God’s creation, but Adam was inferior according to Psalm 8 to the heavenly hosts because human beings were not created immortal as Psalm 82 points out the sons of God were. Also the tree of life being in the garden would serve no purpose if Adam was immortal.

**So to answer your question**

In view of the fact that satan was envious of this one cherub who was God and was called the son of God, satan was convinced that God was hiding something from him that prevented him from also being God like this cherub (Jesus).

When he confronted Eve, satan was merely projecting his frustration onto Eve. He was convinced that God was hiding something from him and if Eve would eat of the forbidden fruit then she too would at least know as much as he knew. Certainly satan had skills and knowledge intuitively that Adam and Eve had no idea about.

It’s possible that satan was banking on eating the fruit himself to gain this knowledge but couldn’t risk ruining his chances. He is extremely shrewd.

Everything he achieves is through legal technicalities and he perpetuates most of his success by keeping people in the dark. If people could know how weak his position actually is, his bluff would be called and he’d lose a lot of ground.

The idea that satan might have wanted to eat of this forbidden fruit isn’t far fetched considering manna was called the food of angels and satan is an angel. Therefore the implication is that angels eat (at least something).

By deceiving Eve to eat, and bringing sin into the world satan stole the dominion from man and supplanted God by establishing himself as god over God’s creation. On technicality if God were to justly apply justice to satan then God would be forced to also judge mankind. So instead of immediately effectuating justice and destroying all of humanity through Adam, God allowed humanity to perpetuate in a fallen state with the intention that every individual could chose God on an individual basis, where Adam has failed. He even provided the ultimate sacrifice freely, which essentially gave God the legal right to take full rights and dominion back.

And the most remarkable of all is that God intends to give dominion right back to man who lost it in Eden, God is giving mankind dominion in the new era to come when there will be a new heaven and a new earth.

Just to summarize, satan was bluffing, satan had no idea if Eve would be like God or not, but he was willing to deceive Eve into eating the fruit to see what would happen.

Adam and Eve were already like God because they were made in His image. God does not ‘know’ (experiential) evil because He has never committed it.

Also it’s curious that satan is said to use elohim you will be like elohim. It’s as if he is enticing Eve to achieve something he has, which is the status of an elohim, something  she doesn’t as a human. He was offering her something he couldn’t offer her but was profiting from the fact that he was an elohim even if he was The Elohim. It’s almost reads like he was pretending to be god himself in those moments. You won’t die, look I’m an elohim I if you want to be like me (just like I am like that cherub who visits you every day walking in the garden, that cherub who is called God) then all you need to do is eat the fruit. And Eve was deceived.

Comment: Nothing in the text references the serpent as Satan or any other being. Archaeological records show that, for several Levantine & Mesopotamian cultures serpents were to femininity & fertility what bulls were to masculinity & virility. This is the more likely symbolism behind the serpent motif, but even this comes from archaeology and not Hermeneutics.

Comment: @RubelliteFae “He laid hold of the dragon, *that serpent of old*, who is the Devil and Satan, and bound him for a thousand years;”
‭‭Revelation‬ ‭20:2‬ ‭plus the LXX uses the same word as John in revelation ὄφις further the Hebrew נחשׁ because in its original form did not have the niqqud depending on the niqqud placement changes the word from a verb, adjective and noun. As a noun it’s a serpent, as a verb it’s to deceive and as an adjective it to shine brightly. Should Moses have meant all three it’s a bright shining serpentine creature that deceives. It’s ALL in the text!

Comment: I can't understand seriously attempting to use Revelations to discuss Genesis

Comment: There is nothing to understand. Firstly I included other supporting arguments directly from the Hebrew, no need to get hung up on one point, second the NT response is equivalent to  someone responding on this stack with an explanation except much closer to the original event, original language/culture/history and original supporting documents. Third there is the inspiration of Scripture by the Holy Spirit that reveals and maintains a common thread in the Bible regardless the author, language, culture or time period.